# Kendo upload loses class when events added

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload

Ive got a kendoupload in my gridview:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files")
 )
```

And this works fine:

[image]

But when i add events to the upload:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files")
            .Events(events => events
            .Complete("onUpload")
            .Remove("onRemoveSuccess"))
)
```

It loses all css-classes:

[image]

Comment: have you defined your onUpload() and onRemoveSuccess() function?

Comment: no but now i have and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it just works according to docs.

Complete handler: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/upload#events-complete

> > **complete**
> >
> > Fires when all active uploads have completed either successfully or with errors.
> >
> > Note: The complete event fires only when the upload is in **async mode**.

Async mode: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/web/upload/modes#asynchronous-mode

> > **Asynchronous mode**
> >
> > In this mode the Upload requires dedicated server handlers to store and remove uploaded files. Files are uploaded immediately or, optionally, after user confirmation. The upload request is executed out-of-band without interrupting the page flow.
> >
> > The async mode is implemented using the HTML5 File API. **The upload will gracefully degrade** and continue to function in legacy browsers using a hidden IFRAME.

So that's it - subscribing to `complete` you forcing `legacy` look & feel for *legacy* browsers.